# Inverse Schur complement

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, block-matrices, schur-complement

Suppose that the square matrix $M$ with dimensions $(n+m) \times  (n+m)$ is partitioned into four submatrix blocks as

$$M_{(n+m) \times (n+m)} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{n \times n } & B_{n \times m} \\ C_{m \times n}&D_{m \times m}\\ \end{pmatrix}.$$

With $A$ and $D$ invertible, we have the Schur complements

$$M/A = D-CA^{-1}B, \quad M/D = A-BD^-1C.$$

Further, partitioned inversion is

$$M^{-1 =} \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ C&D\\ \end{pmatrix}^{-1}= \begin{pmatrix} A^{-1} + A^{-1} B(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1} & -A^{-1 }B(M/A)^{-1} \\ -(M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1} & (M/A)^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$
$$=\begin{pmatrix}(M/D)^{-1} & -(M/D)^{-1}BA^{-1} \\ -D^{-1}C(M/D)^{-1}& D^{-1} + D^{-1} C(M/D)^{-1}BD^{-1}\end{pmatrix}.$$

I can't prove $$ D^{-1} C(M/D)^{-1} = (M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}.$$

Could you give me some hint?

Comment: I actually solve this problem, do i have to just delete it?

Comment: You can post your answer for future reference.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, here is an argument:

Showing that $ D^{-1} C(M/D)^{-1} = (M/A)^{-1}CA^{-1}$ is equivalent to showing that

$$ (M/A) D^{-1} C= CA^{-1}(M/D).$$

One can unpack the LHS and repack it into the RHS to verify this:

\begin{align*}
(M/A) D^{-1} C
&= (D-CA^{-1}B)D^{-1}C\\
&=(I - CA^{-1}BD^{-1})C\\
&=C - CA^{-1}BD^{-1}C\\
&= C(I-A^{-1}BD^{-1}C)\\
&= CA^{-1}(A-BD^{-1}C)
=CA^{-1}(M/D).
\end{align*}